# Downgrade Graph Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-bolt

I have a Neo4J Server running in a Linux VM hosted in Azure.

I used version 3.1.3 and I just upgrade to version 3.2 with setting `dbms.allow_format_migration=true`

Sadly, I can't access anymore to the Neo4J browser cause I am facing the same problem as this one : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/511

I tried to go back to version 3.1.3 but get the following error :

> UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException : Not possible to upgrade a
>   store with version 'v0.A.8 to current store version 'v0.A.7' (Neo4j
>   3.1.3)

Do you know if it is actually possible to adapt the database to an anterior version ?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the upgrade guide it is not possible to reverse this.
See [here](https://neo4j.com/guides/upgrade/) (section: **Is the Store Upgrade Reversible?**).

Did you back up the data before the upgrade?

Comment: Ok, thank you. No, I did not. So as the upgrade was successful I am guessing I can't get it back ? I am still in a developement environnement so It is not very very important

Comment: Correct, I don't believe there's any way to downgrade the db. This is why backing up is always recommended before any db upgrade.